# JQuery: TableSort.js: keep added css classes to elements

Tags: jquery, css, tablesorter

I'm using Tablesort.js to dynamically sort a one page table by clicking on th elements.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-For-Sortable-Searchable-Tables-Tablesort.html

It does just what I need, and works like a charm, but upon doing a sort, all dynamically added classes to the `<tr>` and `<td>` elements are stripped. (so it looks right upon page load, do a sort = all specific row styling is gone.). Each `<tr>` has different classes added to it via a php call.

I think it's in this part of the Tablesort.js

```
// Generate a new clean row based on an array
  function newRow(arr) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
      var td = $('<td>'+arr[i]+'</td>').css('white-space','wrap');
      row.append(td);
    };
    return row;
  };
```

Much googling but no joy.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Some of these table sort scripts need a `<thead>` and `<tbody>` to make them work.  Did you try that?

Comment: it could also be the case that the plugin kills your css classes. find a better one.

Comment: Thanks. It actually works great, apart fromt stripping of the extra classes. I thought that perhaps there was some way of storing the classes and then put them back in. Or take the '$('<tr>'<'tr>')' bit and use some kind of an OR statement so like:  

'row = $('<tr class="this"></tr>)' OR '<tr class="that"></tr>' OR '<tr class="the-other"></tr>');'

but not sure